# Extract item ID from ebay link

Tags: java, parsing

I need ebay item ID from link for my JAVA/JSP app.
There are two ways extract it directly from link
or
Download full page and use html parser to get item ID.

But downloading full page will slow my app.

Is there a way to extract item ID in JAVA/JSP from link?

> http://www.ebay.com/itm/ASSORTED-COLORS-BACK-BATTERY-HOUSING-COVER-CASE-REPLACEMENT-FOR-IPHONE-5-/281163250779?pt=US_Cell_Phone_PDA_Cases&var=580223102484&hash=item4176a2bc5b

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Item ID forms part of the url, does not it?

Comment: Yes it is in ebay url, but there are different type of url to same item, visit ebay and keep your eye on url bar

Comment: Lovepreet, while I took the time to answer your question (or what I think that you have asked) you should read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide to avoid further downvoted questions and increase your chances of receiving good answers. While we are a beginner friendly community, your question is vague, shows no research effort (what is the Item ID?) and no real code. Sounds like you are trying to ask for a solution to a problem that you haven't really understood.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the eBay item ID# is always (afaik) part of the view item page URL, but there are many different formats for that URL that have evolved over the years, and that handle different variations of user behavior and traffic flow.

Here are some examples:

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260134059871

http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&&item=360083468950ssPageName=ADME:B:BCA:GB:1120&ssPageName=ADME:B:BCA:GB:1120

http://buy.id.ebay.com/buying/id/display/270303575025_HUGE-ESTATE-LIQUIDATION-COINS-GOLD-SILVER-FACE-PCGS-NR

http://cgi.ebay.com/1986-First-Steps-In-Quilting_W0QQitemZ%20270298752777QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item360080169380

http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=190359926860

http://cgi.ebay.com/370433488875

...and I have even more in my notes.

A quick and dirty way of extracting the item number without having to mind all of these historical variations is to pluck out the first 11-13 digit number in the URL. I bet 99% of the time that'll work. The rest of the time you might miss the occasional 10- or 14-digit eBay item ID#, or you may get the seller who includes a long part number in the title.

Comment: the 2nd one should be &ss... after the item #, right? you have two && instead before the item

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct, thank you. I'm not sure how that typo appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the Item "ID" is the last component of the URL path, just before the query parameters, here is one of the many methods that can be used to extract it:

```
public long getEBayItemNumber(String ebayURL) throws MalformedURLException {
    final URL url = new URL(ebayURL);
    final String path = url.getPath(); 
    final String itemNumber = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return Long.parseLong(itemNumber);
}
```

Usage example:

```
long itemNumber = getEBayItemNumber("http://www.ebay.com/itm/ASSORTED-COLORS-BACK-BATTERY-HOUSING-COVER-CASE-REPLACEMENT-FOR-IPHONE-5-/281163250779?pt=US_Cell_Phone_PDA_Cases&var=580223102484&hash=item4176a2bc5b");
```

While your question is not clear about what the Item "ID" is supposed to be, the extracted number (`281163250779`) works on the eBay search bar and is reported as "*eBay item number*"  on the item description.

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/gMCfqK).

---

I wouldn't put this method into a [JSP declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajq.html), I wouldn't use scriptlets (or pure JSP for all it is worth) at all, and I would seriously rethink my architecture before doing any kind of business processing in my view layer.